# How to use Regex to select multiple line

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string in form of HTML Text -

```
=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09href=3D"https://web.company.net/#/set-passwor=
d?token=3DeyJ0eFtehgeRs1QiLLKDHDSiOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiZTM4ZTMwMGItNWM5=
Zi00MTg1LThhY2EtNTVkYWEwYzE1ZjIzIiwidGVybXNfYWNjZXBBDHSdndsuOIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ=
0MzI0NDk3LCJleHAiOjE2NDQ0OTcyOTcsIm5iZiI6MTY0NDMyNDU1N30.lRetwJcg9Gf6upQYx6_=
RonwGWjAcxvkE3szhj5Akxbrk&region=3D"=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09style=3D"height: 40px; v-text-anchor: middle; wi=
```

dth: 300px"

The following string(dynamic token) needs to be extracted-

```
3DeyJ0eFtehgeRs1QiLLKDHDSiOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiZTM4ZTMwMGItNWM5=
Zi00MTg1LThhY2EtNTVkYWEwYzE1ZjIzIiwidGVybXNfYWNjZXBBDHSdndsuOIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ=
0MzI0NDk3LCJleHAiOjE2NDQ0OTcyOTcsIm5iZiI6MTY0NDMyNDU1N30.lRetwJcg9Gf6upQYx6_=
RonwGWjAcxvkE3szhj5Akxbrk
```

How can this be done using Regex?

Actively looking forward to some suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit to define rules for determining where the string of interest begins and ends.

Answer (score 1):

Can use **MULTILINE** flag with the regexp 'token=([^&]+)'.

Try this:

```python
import re

html = '''
=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09href=3D"https://web.company.net/#/set-passwor=
d?token=3DeyJ0eFtehgeRs1QiLLKDHDSiOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiZTM4ZTMwMGItNWM5=
Zi00MTg1LThhY2EtNTVkYWEwYzE1ZjIzIiwidGVybXNfYWNjZXBBDHSdndsuOIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ=
0MzI0NDk3LCJleHAiOjE2NDQ0OTcyOTcsIm5iZiI6MTY0NDMyNDU1N30.lRetwJcg9Gf6upQYx6_=
RonwGWjAcxvkE3szhj5Akxbrk&region=3D"=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09style=3D"height: 40px; v-text-anchor: middle; wi=
dth: 300px"
'''

m = re.search(r'token=([^&]+)', html, re.MULTILINE)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
3DeyJ0eFtehgeRs1QiLLKDHDSiOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiZTM4ZTMwMGItNWM5=
Zi00MTg1LThhY2EtNTVkYWEwYzE1ZjIzIiwidGVybXNfYWNjZXBBDHSdndsuOIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ=
0MzI0NDk3LCJleHAiOjE2NDQ0OTcyOTcsIm5iZiI6MTY0NDMyNDU1N30.lRetwJcg9Gf6upQYx6_=
RonwGWjAcxvkE3szhj5Akxbrk
```

Comment: you can use this: `token=([.\s\S]+?(?=&))` . Then you don't need multiline ;) Great answer though

Answer (score 0):

A variation of @CodeMonkey answer without the need of `re.MULTILINE`

```
import re

html = '''
=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09href=3D"https://web.company.net/#/set-passwor=
d?token=3DeyJ0eFtehgeRs1QiLLKDHDSiOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1dWlkIjoiZTM4ZTMwMGItNWM5=
Zi00MTg1LThhY2EtNTVkYWEwYzE1ZjIzIiwidGVybXNfYWNjZXBBDHSdndsuOIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ=
0MzI0NDk3LCJleHAiOjE2NDQ0OTcyOTcsIm5iZiI6MTY0NDMyNDU1N30.lRetwJcg9Gf6upQYx6_=
RonwGWjAcxvkE3szhj5Akxbrk&region=3D"=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09style=3D"height: 40px; v-text-anchor: middle; wi=
dth: 300px"
'''

m = re.search(r'token=([.\s\S]+?(?=&))', html, re.+)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```